# Offset command in Revit API

Tags: c#, .net, revit-api

How can I use the offset command in my C# plugin? I have the list of lines/arcs to include in the offset and the offset value. I can't find the command to use.

I thought that the `ElementTransformUnit` class contains something to do it but it seems that it doesn't...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no Offset command that I'm aware of, but you could make one pretty easily I think using the `ElementTransformUtils.CopyElement` method instead. Try something like this:

```
    static ElementId Offset(this Element originalelement, double offsetamount, string offsetdirection)
    {
        ElementId newelement = null;
        Document curdoc = originalelement.Document;
        LocationPoint elp = originalelement.Location as LocationPoint;
        XYZ elem_location = null;

        switch(offsetdirection.ToUpper())
        {
            default:
                break;

            case "X":
                elem_location = new XYZ(offsetamount, 0.0, 0.0) + elp.Point;
                break;

            case "Y":
                // code for Y
                break;

            case "Z":
                // code for Z
                break;
        }

        try
        {
            using (Transaction tr_offset = new Transaction(curdoc, "Offsetting element"))
            {
                tr_offset.Start();
                newelement = ElementTransformUtils.CopyElement(curdoc, originalelement.Id, elem_location).FirstOrDefault();
                tr_offset.Commit();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command Failed. See below: \n" + e.StackTrace.ToString());
        }

        return newelement;
    }
```

might be better if you made a Direction enum or something like that but that should work for your purposes, I think.